# Azure web app get deployed but wrong content in wwwroot folder

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have a dotnet 6 solution which I deploy with azure-devops in Azure Webapp.

this is part of my yml:

```
            - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
              displayName: 'Deploy WebApp'
              inputs:
                ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
                azureSubscription: 'xxx'
                appType: 'webApp'
                WebAppName: 'default-customer'
                deployToSlotOrASE: true
                ResourceGroupName: 'xxx'
                SlotName: 'production'
                enableCustomDeployment: true
                DeploymentType: 'webDeploy'
                packageForLinux: '$(pipeline.workspace)/drop/WebApp.zip'
                JSONFiles: '**/appsettings.json'
```

it worked for a while but now suddenly when I deploy it didn't work anymore. Actually it should copy the builded solution into the wwwroot folder. but now when I deploy it show me that is was successful, but, in wwwroot is a archive.xml file and a content folder and there in 'D_C'-> 'a' -> '1'-> 's' -> 'myProjectRoot'-> 'obj'->release -> net6.0 -> ... is my project . and in my log in deploy web app I see that instead of extracting the webapp.zip it call the archive button:

> Starting: Deploy WebApp
> ============================================================================== Task         : Azure App Service deploy Description  : Deploy to Azure
> App Service a web, mobile, or API app using Docker, Java, .NET, .NET
> Core, Node.js, PHP, Python, or Ruby Version      : 4.231.1 Author
> : Microsoft Corporation Help         :
> https://aka.ms/azureappservicetroubleshooting
> ============================================================================== Got service connection details for Azure App
> Service:'default-customer' /usr/bin/unzip
> /home/vsts/work/1/drop/WebApp.zip -d
> /home/vsts/work/_temp/temp_web_package_9100078503110456 Archive:
> /home/vsts/work/1/drop/WebApp.zip

do you have any suggestion, why it happen?

Comment: My guess would be that your build has changed.   Does the current pipeline work fine if you trigger it with an old build artifact that did work?    Seems like `WebApp.zip` is using the full path from the build server (`C_D/a/1/s` looks like a folder you build from), and it should only contain the files you wish to deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem was that I have a Web app with windows as operating system but the virtual machine that I referenced in my Yml file was Linux.

> vmImage: 'windows-latest'

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check with the following things to fix the issue:

1. In the build job, reference below steps to configure your build pipeline.

   Use the [**DotNetCoreCLI@2 task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/dotnet-core-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines) instead of the [VSBuild@1 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/vsbuild-v1?view=azure-pipelines) (or [MSBuild@1 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/msbuild-v1?view=azure-pipelines)) to build. If using the **`VSBuild@1`** task (or **`MSBuild@1`** task) to build and generate the ZIP file, the ZIP file will contain the unnecessary folder structure "**`D_C/a/1/s/myProjectRoot/obj/release/net6.0`**", just as the issue you are facing.

```yaml
jobs:
- job: build
  displayName: Build
  steps:
  # Build the web app and generate the ZIP file.
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'dotnet publish'
    inputs:
      command: publish
      projects: 'path/to/WebApp.csproj'
      arguments: '-c $(BuildConfiguration) -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/WebApp.zip'

  # Publish the ZIP file as a pipeline artifact.
  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: 'Publish Pipeline Artifact'
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/WebApp.zip'
      artifact: drop
```

2. In the deploy job (or release pipeline), reference below steps to configure your pipeline.

```yaml
steps:
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Deploy WebApp'
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'xxxx'
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: 'xxxx'
    deployToSlotOrASE: true
    ResourceGroupName: 'xxxx'
    SlotName: 'production'
    enableCustomDeployment: true
    DeploymentType: 'webDeploy'
    packageForLinux: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/WebApp.zip'
    JSONFiles: '**/appsettings.json'
```

In addition, if some artifact files existed in the old app version but no longer exist in the new version, and you want to remove the legacy additional files when deploying the new version, on the **`AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4`** task, you can set "**`RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag: true`**".

Comment: I found the problem. The problem was that I have a Web app with windows as operating system but the virtual machine that I referenced in my Yml file was Linux. But tnx for taking your time and answering me :D